# Importing java files from different folders?

Tags: java

OK, so I have been searching the web for about an hour, but i haven't found a solution for my Computer Science class. So, I have two folders, lets say folder1 and folder2, and in those folders I have .java files. In folder1 I have folder1.java file, and in folder2 I have folder2.java file.

In folder2.java I only have methods, so it looks like this:

```
class folder2{
     public static String ........
   //here are all of the methods
}
```

And in folder1.java I have the execution of those methods in folder2.java:

```
class folder1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       executeMethodFromFolder2JavaFile();
    }
 }
```

How could I do this?

Comment: You will find it useful to read of packages, jars and class paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with the process you are following. This shouldn't be this hard. Perhaps you are following the wrong tutorial, or the wrong principles. I am taking this opportunity to clarify this once and for all.

Note that example code should be exemplary. There is no need to write something in haste to finish it quickly. Ironically, you end up spending more time when you do that.

First of all, you should be paying attention to *names*: names of classes, methods, fields, variables and packages (spend some time on what each of these mean). It's not a commandment of any sort, but just a convenience. The rules are not complicated, in fact pretty straightforward:

1. Name classes as you would name physical entities with capitalized (first character uppercased) names. After all, Java is a programming language that primarily promoted object oriented thinking. After you have abstracted out entities, you name them clearly and simply. Examples are: `Employee`, `Student`, `Fish`, `Square`, `City`, `State`, `Person` etc.
2. Name methods as behaviors and variables as temporary things. These names should start with a lower case letter. Examples of method names are `walk`, `run`, `draw`, `read`, `write` etc. Examples of field and variable names are `color`, `state`, `ready` etc. The variables known as *loop variables* should be named as `i`, `j`, `k` etc.

Note, there are violations of these that you see (e.g. the only method in Java that makes a class executable is rather strangely named `main`, but let's just accept that apparent anomaly without a grudge).

Now, applying it to your case, let's just start with two classes `Shape` and `Painter`. The former represents a shape that the latter can, for example, `draw`. There is no need to start with packages right away. 
I will be using Unix syntax in the following example:

1. Open your editor. Create a file named Shape.java and add the contents.
2. In the **same folder** on your computer, create another class called Painter.java.

> ```
> Shape.java
>
> public class Shape {
>     public void draw() {
>         System.out.println("Shape#draw");
>     }
> }
>
> Painter.java
>
> public class Painter {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>          Shape shape = new Shape();
>          shape.draw();
>     }
> }
> ```

That's it. Compile Painter.java and run it:

1. `javac` Painter.java
2. `java` Painter

> ```
> ➜  /tmp javac Painter.java  
> ➜  /tmp java Painter  
> Shape#draw
> ```

Now introduce the packages. Let's put Painter in a package named *actor* and Shape in *thing*. Simply speaking, packages are folders on a file system. They have a use as logically combining a functionality as a module, a unit.

1. mkdir thing actor
2. mv Shape.java thing
3. mv Painter.java actor

> ```
> ➜  /tmp cat thing/Shape.java actor/Painter.java 
> package thing;
> class Shape {
>     public void draw() {
>         System.out.println("Shape#draw");
>     }
> }
> package actor;
> import thing.Shape; // need to import Shape from thing package now
> class Painter {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>          Shape shape = new Shape();
>          shape.draw();
>     }
> }
> ```

Note that we added the `package` lines in both files appropriately.

1. javac actor/Painter.java -- this is because we moved the Painter.java to a *package* named `actor`. Note that `javac` was smart enough to find out where the Shape.java is (it is now in a subfolder named `thing` of the current folder).
2. java actor.Painter -- since the class is now in a package named `actor`, you have to tell `java` to run it so.

> ```
> `Shape#draw`
> ```

Why is that hard to follow **to begin with**? Of course, you should quickly learn to use a good IDE for Java. The use of an IDE is a must if you were to do any coding in Java effectively.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I read your comment thoroughly and I think I get it now. Thanks for your help!